# select rows that have column contains at least one of a multi words sentence(MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Suppose we have a table `Brands` named with a `title` column that can contains a sentence of some words.

Now we have a sentence like **"stack overflow website"** and we want select all records that their title column contains one of that words means **stack** or **overflow** or **website**.

I know that there is `LIKE` operator for similar task But I think it works only for an specific word.

Furthermore, I prefer use one query to doing my desired result.

I thank you If could help to write that query by laravel eloquent.

Comment: I think you should start by writing the raw MySQL query, which attempt you ideally would have shown us in your question.

Comment: i think you want full text searching

Comment: @A.B.Developer check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `explode` function, make it an array of **words**. The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.
Try this:

```
$querySentence = "stack overflow website";

//Using explode function, make it an array of WORDS
$wordsArray = explode(" ", $querySentence);
$dbQuery = Brands::whereIn('title', $wordsArray)->get();
```

More about [**Laravel whereIn**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses)

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by performing multiple like statements. like so:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE info LIKE '%stack%' OR info LIKE '%overflow%' OR info LIKE '%website%';
```

Note that this will not perform very well on large data structures. If you have a large database, I would advise using something like ElasticSearch instead, but at the very least take a good look at the index of your table.

Answer (score 1):

this query may help
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%stack%' OR COLUMN  LIKE '%overflow%' OR COLUMN  LIKE '%website%'

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. Use `%` when using `LIKE` to achieve it. Like so:

`Select * from brands where title LIKE '%stack%' OR title LIKE '%overflow%' OR title LIKE '%website%'`.

It selects the letter/s that it has. For example, if you just search *sta*, it returns the *stack*, because it has the letters of *sta* inside of *stack*.

**Update:** *Eloquent*

```
Brands::where('title', 'LIKE', '%stack%')->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%overflow%')->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', '%website%');
```